# Running Cascading using Oozie

Tags: hadoop, cascading

I'm trying to run a Cascading job using Oozie. 
I am getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cascading.tap.hadoop.MultiInputSplit

I am including the cascading jar in the workflow lib, but it is not being included when cascading launches the m/r job.

Is there anyone out there using Cascading along with Oozie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should combine cascading jar with your own jar and give it to workflow/lib.